# How to run an animation before another animation finished with the same speed (duration)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

How to run an animation before another animation finished with the same speed (duration).

I tried doing this using animation controller and animation double with Interval, the first animation runs as I expected but the second animation runs faster than the first one. I think this happened because the second animation Interval was set to 0.5, 1.

This is what I tried using Interval but the second animation is faster than the first one

```
class Ex extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExState createState() => _ExState();
}

class _ExState extends State<Ex> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;

  Animation<double> animation1;
  Animation<double> animation2;
  Animation<double> opacityAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 3));

    animation1 = Tween<double>(
      begin: 250,
      end: 300,
    ).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(curve: Interval(0, 1), parent: animationController))
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      })
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        print(status);
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          animationController.reset();
        } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
          animationController.forward();
        }
      });

    animation2 = Tween<double>(
      begin: 250,
      end: 300,
    ).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(curve: Interval(0.5, 1), parent: animationController))
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      })
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          animationController.reset();
        } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
          animationController.forward();
        }
      });

    opacityAnimation = Tween<double>(
      begin: 1,
      end: 0,
    ).animate(animationController)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double radius = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          AnimatedCircle(
              height: animation1.value,
              width: animation1.value,
              opacity: opacityAnimation.value,
              radius: radius),
          AnimatedCircle(
              height: animation2.value,
              width: animation2.value,
              opacity: opacityAnimation.value,
              radius: radius),
          AnimatedCircle(height: 250, width: 250, opacity: 1, radius: radius),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**AnimatedCircle Class:**

```
class AnimatedCircle extends StatelessWidget {
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final double opacity;
  final double radius;
  AnimatedCircle(
      {@required this.height,
      @required this.width,
      @required this.opacity,
      @required this.radius});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        height: height,
        width: width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(radius),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(radius),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(radius),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(radius),
          ),
          border: Border.all(
            width: 1.5,
            color: Colors.green.withOpacity(opacity),
            style: BorderStyle.solid,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [staggered animations](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/staggered-animations) to stack more animations one after another and choose start and end interval of the animations.

In your current case, the second animation has less time to finish, therefore runs faster. Eventually you can give one animation interval (0, 0.5) and for second one (0.5, 1)

Hope, it was at least somehow useful. Cheers